# How can I Convert 0 to '-' in .net C# in A DataTable

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, datatable

I am getting a table which has a few columns containing numbers. What I want is to show '-' in case the number is 0. I tried doing it on the front end but it is not working well. bringing the data in DataTable and then when I was trying to convert it directly it is not converting in character but is showing me the ascii value - 45 instead of '-'.

Then I tried to make a new DataTable but that also is not working and throwing errors relating the data type.
Here's what I tried :

```
DataTable kk = _sqlRepository.GetDataTable(str);
DataTable dd = kk.Clone();
for (int i = 0; i < dd.Rows.Count; i++)
{
   dd.Columns[i].DataType = typeof(String);
}
foreach (DataRow row in kk.Rows)
{
   dd.ImportRow(row);
}
```

But this is not working in converting the Table Columns.
Any idea how to do it in C# using the same DataTable or anything it would be really great.
If any further details or information is needed then please let me know.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You need to change type of entire column.  Best way is to add new column to table with type of string.  Then edit existing column and put edited results into new column.  You can later delete the original column.  The new column will be added at the last column in table and you can move the column after you do all the editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your Dto (Data Transfer Object)'s **property** that holds either decimal represented value (5.67 for example) and "-" should be of **type string**.

Example:

```
public class OrderDto
{
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    //public decimal OrderValue { get; set; }
    public string OrderValue { get; set; }
}
```

And your logic should be something like this:

```
if (reader["order_amount"].ToString() == "0")
   {
       order.OrderValue = "-";
   }
else
   {
       order.OrderValue = reader["order_amount"].ToString();
   }
```

Full Example:

```
        try
        {
            var conString = "Data Source=(local);Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=myDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI";
            using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(conString))
            {
                var qry = "SELECT order_date, order_amount FROM myTable";

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, myConnection);

                myConnection.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        var order = new OrderDto();

                        order.OrderDate = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["order_date"].ToString());

                        if (reader["order_amount"] != DBNull.Value)
                        {

                            if (reader["order_amount"].ToString() == "0")
                            {
                                order.OrderValue = "-";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                order.OrderValue = reader["order_amount"].ToString();
                            }

                        }
                        Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(order));
                    }

                    myConnection.Close();
                }
            }

        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {

            Console.WriteLine($"{ex}");
        }
    }
```

Result:

```
{"OrderDate":"2018-01-31T00:00:00","OrderValue":"2"}
{"OrderDate":"2018-05-25T00:00:00","OrderValue":"-"}
{"OrderDate":"2018-05-28T00:00:00","OrderValue":"-"}
{"OrderDate":"2018-05-28T00:00:00","OrderValue":"-"}
{"OrderDate":"2018-05-28T00:00:00","OrderValue":"-"}
{"OrderDate":"2018-05-28T00:00:00","OrderValue":"-"}
```